# SimpleDateFormat in android not incrementing date when changing timezone

Tags: java, android, time, simpledateformat

So I have this code

```
Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy kk:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String date = sdf.format(now);
```

Pretty standard stuff.  However I am getting a weird issue when I convert from Mountain Time at 10/01/2013 18:45:50 I get an output of 10/02/2013 24:45:50.

Seems like a bug to me.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kk` used on SimpleDateFormat formats hours between 01 and 24 (both included). You should use this to have hours formatted between 00 and 23.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 2):

`kk` will give you a value from `01` to `24`. You perhaps want `HH` if you are expecting a value from `00` to `23`.